# asp.net hyperlinkfield set navigateurl "http=blabla/Id=" value from database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, templatefield

I am new to asp.net. Please help. 
I have 2 files. One default.aspx, one default.aspx.cs.

In the default.aspx, I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3366FF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
    <rowstyle backcolor="LightCyan" forecolor="Black" font-italic="true"/>

     <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="PaleTurquoise" forecolor="Black" font-italic="true"/>

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />

        <asp:hyperlinkfield text="Log" navigateurl="http://somelink&RecordId=" target="_blank" ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="Log" />

        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="Delayed Delivery" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My questions:

Column: hyperlink Log:

1. I want to bind it to a column in database called "Base_Id", but when I use DataField="Base_Id" in the hyperlink definition, it gives error;
2. I want to append the base_Id to the end of the url so that it gives navigateurl="http://somelink&RecordId=baseId_value" ; I tried TemplateField, but Visual Studio doesnot recognize it.
3. for the delayed delivery, I need to compare the data and do some math. Is there a way for me to add a function in default.aspx.cs? if there's, could anyone give an example please?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks a lot. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the column

```
  <asp:hyperlinkfield text="Log" navigateurl="http://somelink&RecordId=" target="_blank" ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="Log" />
```

to TemplateColumn and do this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Log" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# GetUrl(Eval("Base_Id"))%>' 
                text="Log"></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in code-behind

```
protected string GetUrl(object id)
{
return "http://somelink&RecordId=" + id;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uroš

Comment: @Uros: Hi thank you for your reply. I tried: <asp:hyperlinkfield text="Event Horizon Log" navigateurl=<%# GetNavigationUrl(Eval("Base_Id"))%> target="_blank"
         ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="Log" /> and added the function: protected string GetNavigationUrl(object base_id)
        {
            return "http://somelink&RecordId=" + base_id;
        } But it gave me error saying that there's no databinding for hyperlinkfield. any ijeas please

Comment: Hi, I revised my post. You forgot to convert your hyperlink field to template field.

Comment: @UrošGoljat : hi hi, i got another mini problem and please help if u have time. I want the hyperlink text showing the base_id, but datafield="base_id" doesn't work since it says it's not an attribute of hyperlink. I used a function that returns the base_id as string and text=returned_string, but is there an easier way like just using some datafieldtext="base_id_column_in_database"? help please. =)

Comment: Hi, you can do this Text='<%#Eval("Base_Id")%>' instead of Text="Log"

Comment: Its really helpful !!